# OpenLDAP won't look at CA certificate

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap, self-signed-certificate

I have set up an LDAP server that I would like to connect to from a client machine. Ubuntu is OS of both server and client, TLS is active and since this is a practice project, all my certificates are self signed.

In order for the client to accept the server's certificate, I have added the certificate of my CA to the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates folder and run `update-ca-certificates`, adding it to the trusted list. (followed [this](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap-with-tls) tutorial). I know the certificate is correct and works, because when I specify the certificate directly while running `ldapsearch -xLLLH ldaps://example.com:636 -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=com" -W -o tls_cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem`, it works as expected.

However, when I try to run `ldapsearch -xLLLH ldaps://example.com:636 -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=com" -W` (without the certificate path) I get a "TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)" error. I have added these settings to /etc/ldap.conf:

```
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem
tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs
```

but this appears to change nothing. Looking at the strace of the command, it genuinely doesn't try to open the certificate once. Overwriting the environment variable LDAPTLS_CACERT and setting it to the path of the certificate fixes it temporarily, but that will reset at every reboot. What else could I do?

Comment: Seems more like ldapsearch is not finding the certificate in the location that you want.

Comment: Are you sure it should not be in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` rather than `/etc/ldap.conf`?

Comment: @Bib+ the man page on my Ubuntu (20.04 focal) says `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` -- with `~/.ldaprc ~/ldaprc $PWD/ldaprc` as alternatives. It also says TLS_CACERTDIR is ignored with gnuTLS 'on Debian' and ldd confirms (Ubuntu) ldapsearch uses gnuTLS and not OpenSSL -- but TLS_CACERT should work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, well, either way, it does not seem to be `/etc/ldap.conf`. They also passed `tls_cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem`, so that suggests the correct def, case not withstanding.

Comment: It may be helpful to get some debug output from ldapsearch (option `-v`)

Comment: @Bib The configuration file was generated in that location automatically. I don't have an /etc/openldap or /etc/ldap directory on the client machine

Comment: Then create them & see if it works. Why not run `strace` against `ldapsearch` without the `-D` switch & look to see what it is accessing.

Comment: Can you check the TLS connection using `openssl s_client -connect example.com:636 -showcerts`? See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/719047/510395).

Comment: @Bib Creating the directory manually actually worked, I can't believe it. What a dumb issue! Thank you so much. 
Looking at the strace, it appears to also open 330 other certificates, many after it already found the correct one. Is that normal? (It also happens when I specify the CA certificate with the -o option)

Comment: I am guessing it is opening & checking the signing cert trail, but who knows...